# Pass result of git diff -S<string> to git restore/add -p

Tags: git

I'm in a situation where I changed a couple of files and need to undo some changes that include a certain string `<string>`.

I usually use `git restore --patch` in such occasion, but here it becomes tedious, because there are only a few changes which contain `<string>`.

On the other hand I can clearly filter all the desired hunks with `git diff -S<string>`.
Is there a way to pass those filtered results to `git restore` or something similar?

Comment: What operating system are you on? (Windows/Mac/Linux/etc.)

Comment: I'm currently on Windows, but also interested in a linux solution. An OS indepedent concept would be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the lower-level commands for this,

```
git diff -R -S somestring | git apply -3
```